# Connect to SQL Server with Spring Boot and JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I try to make a connection to an SQL server from my Spring Boot application.

I receive this **error** when starting my application:

```
jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host MSSQLSERVER01, port 63251 has failed. 
Error: "MSSQLSERVER01. Verify the connection properties. 
Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. 
Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

This is my **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLSERVER01;DatabaseName=learning;port=63251
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=dbo
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

I wasn't allowed to paste my **pom.xml** file here, since it said that my post consisted mainly of code instead of explanation, which it wouldn't allow. Here is the link to my pom.xml: https://justpaste.it/99k7a

Any ideas on what I have done wrong? I am new to Java and Spring Boot, btw. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried moving port? like jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLSERVER01:63251;DatabaseName=learning

Comment: @Conrad It didn't seem to do the job (I still get the same error), but thanks a lot for trying to help. If I may ask a follow up question: Is it important to include `spring.datasource.password`? I use Windows Authentication so I am not sure about the password though

Comment: What is MSSQLSERVER01? It seems more like network problem, but adding password shouldn't break anything :P

Comment: @Conrad MSSQLSERVER01 is the Server name of the SQL Server I am using. In MSSQLSERVER01, I have a database named "learning". And really, so it would be a bad idea? I have just seen plenty examples where people include password, so I thought I may need to :D

Comment: I mean it shouldn't break anything. Also try jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:63251;serverName=MSSQLSERVER01;DatabaseName=learning
If it won't work read more about sqlserver uri here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Conrad Hey again Conrad, thanks for the advice. Before inserting your string, I tried leaving out this part "serverName=MSSQLSERVER01", so only trying to connect to localhost:63251 instead, and now I got another error: `"Login failed for user 'dbo'. ClientConnectionId:0ba72c87-2ce3-4660-bf73-c6564d6560c8"` I guess that is a good sign that it at least tried to log me in, right? :-D so I may have to find out what the password is. I really appreciate the help. And that link looks very useful for making sure my connection properties are set up correctly.

Comment: On another note, it looks like for Windows Authentication, I need to add the attribute `integratedSecurity=true`. I got this information from reading your useful link

Comment: @Conrad It turns out now, that...: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication." I will research another driver I can use. Your help pushed me in the right direction!

Comment: For anyone curious, this fixed the driver issue: devdummy.com/2019/10/resolved-sql-error-this-driver-is-not.html

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for all the help, it is working now. I appreciate it a lot. The least I can do is to - if you make an answer - make that the accepted answer, so you get the points/recognition in solving this problem. Otherwise, have a good day and thanks again.

Comment: You might want to add it as separate answer. I'm glad it worked out :)